# I am trying to make a simple gradient descent algorithm in python, but it goes back up after passing through the lowest point

Tags: python, algorithm, math, gradient, gradient-descent

## Problem

I am trying to build a simple gradient descent algorithm and plot it on a heatmap.

I assume there are better ways to do this, but I have to use this methodology.

My professor and I have very similar code but we cannot understand why mine behaves differently. Once the lowest point is reached, it should just turn around the lowest point. It works for my professor, but mine goes back up and stops in the middle of nowhere for some reason that we cannot figure out.

Let me be precise, it does not stop because the number of iterations (passed as a parameter of the function) is reached, but the gradient vector becomes very small in a random place as it should happen at the lowest point.

Here is my code :

```py
from math import cos, sin, exp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import derivative

def f(x, y):
    return 4 * exp(-((x**2)/2 + (y**2)/2)) * sin(x*(y-1/2)) * cos(x/2 + y)

precision = 10e-5

# Derivee par rapport a x
def ddx(f):
    return lambda x, y: derivative(f, x, dx=precision, n=1, args=(y,))

# Derivee par rapport a y
def ddy(f):
    return lambda x, y: derivative(f, y, dx=precision, n=1, args=(x,))

# grad(f) retourne la fonction vectorielle de deux variables réelles : (x, y) -> ∇(x, y)
def grad(f):
    return lambda x, y: np.array([ddx(f)(x, y), ddy(f)(x, y)])

def display_heatmap_with_gradient_descent(f, a, b, c, d, n, x0, y0, iterations, h):
    x = np.arange(a,b,n)
    y = np.arange(c,d,n)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # préparation du maillage
    f_vect = np.vectorize(f) # transformation de f en une fonction vectorielle
    Z = f_vect(X,Y) # calcul des images

    # Trace la carte de couleur
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    colormap = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap='YlGnBu')
    fig.colorbar(colormap)

    # Fonction gradient pour f
    gradient = grad(f)

    # Ajoute la descente de gradient
    x = x0
    y = y0
    for i in range(iterations):
        vecteur = -gradient(x, y)
        new_x = x + h * vecteur[0]
        new_y = y + h * vecteur[1]
        print("Itération " + str(i) + " : (" + str(x) + ", " + str(y) + ") -> (" + str(new_x) + ", " + str(new_y) + ")")
        print("\tVecteur : " + str(vecteur))
        ax.plot([x, new_x], [y, new_y], color='black')
        x = new_x
        y = new_y

    # Affiche le point d'arrêt
    ax.plot([x], [y], marker='o', markersize=3, color="red")
        
    plt.show()

display_heatmap_with_gradient_descent(f, -5, 5, -5, 5, 0.05, -0.36, -0.39, 100, 0.1)
```

## Update

I do not know if this is the only problem, but I made some tests with my gradient function, and apparently there is something wrong with it.

For example, I tested the following code :

```py
print(grad(lambda x, y : x**2 - y**2)(1., 1.))
```

And it gives me `[2., 2.]`, but it should be `[2., -2.]` since ddx is 2x and ddy is -2x for f = x^2 - y^2.

So I guess this is where the problem lies but I do not understand what is wrong with my `grad` function.

In addition, if the problem is in the `grad` function, it is strange that my algorithm almost works and goes through the lowest point.

With such a core problem, I would assume it would do anything.

## Track

Again, this might not be the only problem, but at least it should be part of it.

If I do `grad(f)(x, y)` where x=y, then my `ddx` and `ddy` called by `grad` will return the same functions. It explains why I get [2., 2.] instead of [2., -2.] for `grad(lambda x, y : x**2 - y**2)(1., 1.)`.

**How can I process to get different partial derivatives with x = y ?**

Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just a track : I can't help you more, but I remember a piece of advice from an old course:
  "Failure to converge or taking too long to get the minimum value implies that our step size is wrong."
  (alpha is a coeff to adjust the step size )
  "if alpha is too large, the gradient descent may exceed the minimum: it may not converge or even diverge"

Comment: @pirela Thank you for your comment. I already tried to change the step size, but it does not seem to change anything. In addition, if for example my step size was too large and I "jumped above" the lowest point, then my gradient would change direction and I would keep turning around the lowest point without fiding it precisely. However, as you can see in my update, there must be a problem with my `grad` function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but it looks like the derivative() function attempts the give a numerical approximation since I can't see anywhere where you've computed the fomulae for the partial derivatives. I suspect there's a problem with the arguments you've supplied for this function but not knowing python, I can't help. Why not just compute the formulae for ddx(x,y) and ddy(x,y). It would probably be more accurate too.

Comment: @SimonGoater the reason why I am not computing the ddx and ddy formulas on paper and hard-coding them is because I want the code to be generic. If I change the `f` function, the code should still work. However, you are right, as I explained in the Track section of my question I don't numerically compute ddx and ddy either and that is the problem. I think I found the solution, I will update my post soon. Thank you for contributing.

Comment: Matteo, it looks like `derivative` is not understanding that its argument `f` is a function of two arguments. Try rewriting the call to derivative so that you supply a function of one argument, especially for `ddy`. That is, try: `derivative (lambda y1: f (x, y1), y, <other args>)`

Comment: Thank you @RobertDodier this is essentially what I did to fix my problem and everything works fine now. I will update my solution post this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The problem was in effect with the `grad` function or rather with the `ddx` and `ddy` functions. These two functions were actually the same, except I was swapping x and y.

In other words, I wasn't computing the partial derivatives correctly which caused my gradient to be wrong and my algorithm to not work properly.

Here is the part of the code that has been modified, the rest is unchanged:

```py
def f_replace_y(f, y):
    return lambda x: f(x, y)

def f_replace_x(f, x):
    return lambda y: f(x, y)

# Dérivée partielle de f par rapport à x
def ddx(f):
    return lambda x, y : derivative(f_replace_y(f, y), x, dx=precision, n=1)

# Dériavée partielle de f par rapport à y
def ddy(f):
    return lambda x, y : derivative(f_replace_x(f, x), y, dx=precision, n=1)
```

However, I still wonder how my previous code could pass through the lowest point given that my partial derivatives were wrong.